# Showing Remaining Session Time in Flask

Tags: python, flask

I want to show the remaining session time on top of the page of my website.

I have used the following code to set session time in my __init.py file

```
from datetime import timedelta


d=timedelta(minutes=5)
app.config['PERMANENT_SESSION_LIFETIME']=d
```

I want to get the remaining session time ? so that i could show it on screen

is there any way to do it in FLASK ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from datetime import datetime ,timedelta

start_time=datetime.now()
d=timedelta(minutes=5)
time_left=d-(datetime.now()-start_time)
time_left.total_seconds()/60
```